# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-k} e^{-a(x+d)^2} dx$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, singularity

I want to solve the following integral:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-k}  e^{-a(x+d)^2} dx$$

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, and $a, d \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$.

When $k =0$, the integral is a standard Gaussian integral. However, when $k > 0$, the problem is not so easy. We see that when $x \rightarrow 0$, the integrand blows up.

We cannot set $I = \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}}{\text{lim}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-k}  e^{-a(x+d)^2} dx $ and then expand $x^{-k}$ into its Maclaurian series because we are integrating over all $x > 0$ and the series converges only within a finite region. Similarly, we cannot put a contour that goes around the singularity because the pole is of higher order. Also, solving as if $k < 0$ and then using analytic continuation of the Gamma function won't work, because $k$ is an integer.

Any ideas? Or does this integral simply not exist?

Thanks

Comment: @YvesDaoust It does?

Comment: Oooops, sorry $0\le k< 1$. The integrand is asymptotic to $x^{-k}e^{-ad^2}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes true, but that still blows up when $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$...and Im not sure how to get rid of that singularity.

Comment: Intuitively this is (a multiple of) the expected value of $|z^{-k}|$ $z\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$.  Notice that the probability density near the pole is not zero, so when the integral around the pole diverges this integral diverges, as happens for $k=1$.

Comment: When $k=0$, we don't get a Gaussian integral?

Comment: @hacatu Okay, so what you are saying is, for $k \geq 1$, we have no hope of solving this.

Comment: The integral converges for $k<1$ and $a>0$ whereas you want $k$ to be a positive integer, so ... . In the case $k<1$ maybe we can get a result using special functions.

Answer (score 1):

This integral does not exist.  Consider the case when $k=1$.  (I think other cases reduce to this via integration by parts.)  We know $\int_0^n\frac{dx}{x}$ diverges.  But our integral $\int_0^n\frac{e^{-a(x+d)^2}dx}{x}\ge\int_0^n\frac{mdx}{x}$ where $m$ is the minimum of $e^{-a(x-d)^2}$ on $[0,n]$.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. However, I seem to have gotten an answer above yours...

Comment: Actually something with integration by parts isn't even needed, $\int_0^n\frac{mdx}{x^k}$ never converges for any positive $k$ so the comparison just generalizes to all such $k$.

Comment: How you do reconcile this with the other answer, which claims to give a solution that does exist?

Comment: The other answer only shows a way to rewrite with u substitution. Any expansion of $(u-\sqrt{a}d)^{-k}$ that actually converges to it around the pole $\sqrt{a}d$ may include terms without a pole there, but must include terms with a pole there.  For instance, a taylor series can never converge at the pole (it can't be centered at a point where the function is undefined and any other point will have a radius of convergence at most the distance to the pole).  A laurent expansion would converge, but have negative powers which have a pole in the same place.

Comment: I thought so. So in other words, the expansion is incorrectly applied, because we are performing integration outside the radius of convergence. Using a Laurent expansion instead won't help us, because the poles will still be there. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\infty x^{-k}e^{-[\sqrt{a}(x+d)]^2}dx$$
$u=\sqrt{a}(x+d)\Rightarrow dx=du/\sqrt{a}$ so we have:
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{\sqrt{a}d}^\infty\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}-d\right)^{-k}e^{-u^2}du$$
$$=a^{(k-1)/2}\int_{\sqrt{a}d}^\infty(u-\sqrt{a}d)^{-k}e^{-u^2}du$$
now try and expand $(u-\sqrt{a}d)^{-k}$ to get this as a series of integrals and then use the incomplete gamma function

Comment: I tried this exact approach, but the series part tripped me up. Which series should I use here? Plus, $k$ is positive..so...

Comment: The taylor series won't work here. Correct? Which series did you use?

Comment: No, just use binomial expansion

Comment: I see what you are saying. So, how you do you reconcile this with the other answer, which says the integral does not exist?

Comment: Looking at: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html It seems the expansion is only valid for $u < \sqrt{ad}$, however, the integration limits clearly go way past that limit.